# How to separate numbers from a slice?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a list with 10 numbers:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

I would like my program to slice every 3 numbers, for example:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

How can I do it?
Grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, with n = 3,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    list := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    for a, n := list, 3; len(a) >= n; a = a[n:] {
        slice := a[:n]
        fmt.Println(slice)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

Answer (score -2):

you could make a something like this (sorry for pseudo code)

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

while (array){
    list = ""
    for($i=1;$i -le 3;$i++){
    list.add = array[$i]
    remove from array the array[$i]
    }
    your list now here (list)

}
```

you could ask the first 3 values and after that you remove it

Comment: As you can see from the tag on the question, the question is about the Go programming language.